# Redirect to another tab after inserting data bootstrap 3.3

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, hash

I am having `multipills.php` and `personal.php`; `multipills.php` with 4 tabs

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li> <a href="#personal" data-toggle="tab"> personal </a></li>
    <li> <a href="#reservation" data-toggle="tab">reservation </a></li>
    <li> <a href="#contact" data-toggle="tab"> contact  </a></li>            
    <li> <a href="#family" data-toggle="tab">family </a></li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-pane active"  name="personal" id="personal">
 <form method="POST" action="personal.php">
<button> SUBMIT </button>
</form>
<div class="tab-pane"  name="reservation" id="reservation">
<form method="POST" action="reservation.php">
<button> SUBMIT </button>
</form>
<div class="tab-pane"  name="contact" id="contact">
<div class="tab-pane "  name="family" id="family">
```

Each tab contain form when I submit a form PERSONAL TAB with the help of `personal.php` it should redirect me to `multipills.php#reservation`.

There is no javascript or jquery on both pages.
If required where should I put script?
`windows.location.href` or `windows.locatin.hash` is not working after inserting data. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post complete files?

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to go about this.

**1) Activate tab server-side**

You need a way to let the server know which pane you want active. Probably with a hidden input in the form in each pane's PHP file.

For example, personal.php may look something like this:

```
<form action="multipills.php" method="post">
    <!-- stuff -->
    <input type="hidden" name="pane" value="personal">
</form>
```

Then multipills.php should have logic to determine

1. What pane is the user currently on?
2. What is the next pane we should show?

Once it knows what pane to show, you can toggle the `active` class on each `tab-pane` to activate the appropriate pane.

```
<div class="tab-pane<?= $currentPane == "personal" ? " active" : ""; ?>" name="reservation" id="reservation">
<!-- Repeat for other tabs. -->
```

**2) Activate tab client-side**

You can accomplish something similar with JavaScript.

personal.php should look something like this:

```
<form action="multipills.php#reservation" method="post">
    <!-- stuff -->
</form>
```

None of the panes would be active by default.

Then you'd add a script in your page somewhere *after* your tabs are defined in markup.

```
<script>
    document.getElementById(window.location.hash).classList.add('active');
</script>
```

Neither solution is complete nor (necessarily) ideal, but hopefully they will get you started on the correct path.